# Is there a maximal daily reputation loss from voting?

Tags: support, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

It is well known that you can only gain 200 points of reputation by upvotes. The rest is discarded, unless it is coming from accepting/accepted answers and bounties.

Suppose that over the next UTC day, a horde of 500 angry users downvote a particular answer, or the body of answers of a certain user, which for some reason doesn't get deleted. Will the user lose the potential 1000 points (and maybe set the record for the most downvoted post in the history of the network)? Or is there a 200 points cutoff after which the downvotes don't cause any more collateral damage to the reputation? If the latter case, will these downvotes still pain the voter by a single point? (I'm assuming the answer to the second question is positive, but I have no idea about the first.)

Comment: Idle curiosity is idle, no doubt about that.

Comment: I am curious, too. I have no idea. We probably need to get the attention of a community manager or a developer.

Comment: Interesting question. I think most peoples' comments/posts get moderator attention by that point, so this hypothetical situation never really comes up. Here's something else to consider: if a maximum reputation loss existed, should there be a badge for losing maximum reputation a number of times in a row? If you think about it, it's really hard to lose that much without getting your comment deleted or removed, lol.

Comment: @daOnlyBG: I think that getting there once merits either a gold badge, or an indefinite suspension/deletion. :-)

Comment: Idle curiosity, but man, nice idle meta thought!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Or both, a gold badge for going full retard and an indefinite suspension (not deletion so other users can glance at the badge) for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. Confirmed by an employee here: [Is there a negative reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46017/259867)

Comment: Oh, shoot. I was looking forward to trying this experiment on someone.

Comment: It doesn't seem about voting. Just about reputation loss cap.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The  positive reputation cap concerns only voting. And this is the context in which the question is posed: does this thing also work in the negative territory? To which the answer is: no.